# iOS - Resize UISwitch in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uinavigationbar, uiswitch

I am trying to use a `UISwitch` in my `UINavigationBar`. I want a smaller switch than the default, so I am scaling the size down with `anonymousSwitch.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.55, 0.55);` When I do this, the switch shrinks, but I cannot figure out how to align it vertically with the other elements in my `UINavigationBar`. 
Here is what it looks like currently:
[image]

Ideally, the `UISwitch` would be spaced away from the 175 `UILabel` as much as the X `UIButton` is spaced from the 175 `UILabel`, and the `UISwitch` would be in a straight line with the rest of the elements in the `UINavigationBar`. I tried doing `switch.center = CGPointMake(switch.center.x, shareButton.center.y)`, but this did not affect the placement of the `UISwitch` at all. 
Is there any way for me to position the switch like I want?

Comment: When using `transform`, I would advice not to use autolayout with it. Constraints don't play very well with `transform`. Remove all constraints, then change `center`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I tried to solve it and came up with this solution.
I don't think it's a perfect solution and might not work on every iOS-Version.

First you need to subclass UISwitch like this:

```
@interface UICustomSwitch : UISwitch

@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat scale;

@end

@implementation UICustomSwitch

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    CGFloat superview_height = self.superview.frame.size.height;
    frame.origin.y = (superview_height - frame.size.height * _scale) / 2;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}

@end
```

The second thing to do is to create and setup your UICustomSwitch like that:

```
UICustomSwitch* switch = [UICustomSwitch new];
switch.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75);
switch.scale = 0.75;
UIBarButtonItem* button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:switch];
```

To create a bigger space between the 175 and the switch you could just add another `UIBarButtonItem` between the 175 and the switch. E.g. a fixed spacer with a specific width.

Like i said, i don't think it's a flawless solution.
In my tests it worked.
Another solution by [0yeoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4903563/0yeoj) (but a little bit adjusted -> always centered for every navigationBar height, for toolbars it's the same, just use `self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height` ):

```
UIView* switch_container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];

UISwitch* switch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:switch_container.bounds];
switch.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75);
switch.center = CGPointMake(switch_container.bounds.size.width/2, switch_container.bounds.size.height/2);
[switch addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[switch_container addSubview:switch];

UIBarButtonItem* button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:switch_container];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving switch with another transform method like,

```
CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xValue, yValue);
```

also you can merge two transform together and give that transform to switch like,

```
CGAffineTransform scale= CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.55, 0.55);

CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 10);

anonymousSwitch.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(scale, translate);
```

Comment: The transform doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i tested..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIButton *xbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    xbutton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 6, 35, 35);
    xbutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];

    UISwitch *switchButton = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    switchButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35);
    switchButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.55, 0.55);
    switchButton.center = CGPointMake(containerView.frame.size.width/2, containerView.frame.size.height/2);
    [containerView addSubview:switchButton];

    UIBarButtonItem *additionalButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:containerView];

    UIBarButtonItem *xBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:xbutton];

    //rearrange it if necessary
    NSArray *arrayButton = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: xBarButton, additionalButton, nil];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = arrayButton;
}.
```

hmm... i haven't DOWNGRADED yet to yosemite so i dont have ios8.3 here this code works perfectly for me though..

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me. Did you test it? 
Tested it on iPhone 6, iOS 8.3.
The way i've done it, does work though.

Comment: On iOS 8.2 actually.. and yes i've just tried it..  i'll edit and place the whole code..

Comment: awkward. I ran it on iPhone 5 (7.1) Simulator just now. Placed a button with my solution and one with yours in a toolbar/navigationbar and your button is not vertically centered. Don't ask me why, i exactly used  your code.

Comment: yeah i think it will not align vertically because you set `switch.center = CGPointMake(switch.center.x, shareButton.center.y)` manually.. and i think same with the other buttons? 

look at how i set my frames.. try copy pasting it and see what happen..

Comment: Using your containerView is making it work. But when toolbar height is changing, the offset would be off.

Comment: ToolBar? i thought is navigationbar? >.< which off? the switch button? so you want it dynamically.. >.< you should have included that to your question..

just edited, check it out.. :)

Comment: Sry to confuse you. It doesn't matter if tool or navigation bar. Both are changing their height in landscape mode on iPhone. And yes i mean the y offset of the switch. As anwser for the question of the op your solution is sufficient. I personally need a dynamic one, like in my answer. Just wanted to add that this problem might occur when using your solution.

Comment: yeah i understand.. have you checked the edited one?
i've inserted `switchButton.center = CGPointMake(containerView.frame.size.width/2, containerView.frame.size.height/2);` 

yeah i know the height becomes 32 when landscaped..

Comment: works perfectly. i just removed the line for setting the frame of the switch and used `UISwitch *switchButton = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:containerView.frame];` Like that i always have the correct center and im gonna get the height from the tool or navigation bar . i think im gonna use this method now, my solution in my answer is more like a hack which maybe isn't working anymore.

Comment: Your answer isn't useless. It works like it should, i just adjusted it a little bit for me, i'll add your method to my answer mentioning that it's your solution in a adjusted way, if that's ok for you?